# Не показывается фото из Инстаграма

Tags: javascript, html, css, php7

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может не отображаться фото из Инстаграма на сайте? Вставил я его с помощью вкладки "Вставка" под фотографией.

```
<div class="instagram_media_1"
```

Посмотреть эту публикацию в Instagram            Публикация от (системный аккаунт) (@ifbest_systemic) 6 Янв 2019 в 8:24 PST

Comment: Код в студию, причин много

Comment: Я поправил, код выложил

Comment: не html код надо нам а js код как вы фетчите фотки из инстаграма какой плагин используете как работаете с API вот это интересно людям

Comment: Я не использую JS для вывода и не пользуюсь CMS

Comment: Не понял, это же не весь код, где закрывающий тег? Где тег `script`? И вообще код фотографии примерно так начинается `<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned da...`. Откуда вы берете ссылку?